# lxml import etree throws can not find reference etree in __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I installed lxml in my virtualenv and able to do this

```
from lxml import html
```

But, what is not working is

```
from lxml import etree
```

It says, can not find reference etree in `__init__.py`. Please help.

[image]

I am on windows and python 3.7.

Comment: Try `from lxml import html, etree`

Comment: But did you try to run the code? Sometimes the ide cannot find the reference, but it works.